# a hard real-time ROS?

Tags: ros, real-time, linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I'm new to ROS and don't know much about it. Is ROS suitable for hard real-time applicaitons?

Has anyone tried to run ROS on a hard real-time Linux, say, Xenomai or RTAI? Or does it make sense to do so?

Thanks,

Zhu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9330/a-hard-real-time-ros?/) by [Zhu](https://answers.ros.org/users/259/zhu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For this kind of requirements we provide [Orocos](http://www.orocos.org). We provide a integration with ROS in our [repository](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kul-ros-pkg) allowing to do your low level real-time control with Orocos and still make use of high level algorithms like the navigation stack from ROS.
This kind of setup was already demonstrated on multiple robots like the RoboEarth Amigo platform, the Kuka Youbot, ...

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-09-28**:
it as real-time as your kernel allows you to be, it differs if you are using regular linux, patched kernel, xenomai ...

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-09-28**:
What real-time mechanism Orocos provide? Hard real-time or Soft real-time? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started working at KULeuven, home of OROCOS but a different department.  Everyone I have met here who is doing hard real-time is using Ubuntu with a xenomai kernel, ROS just as a package manager/build system, and writing all of their code as OROCOS components and running them in the orocos deployer.

I haven't met anyone doing inter-op between Orocos and ROS yet; I read that you can send signals between the two environments with some work, but their workflows and toolsets are mostly orthogonal.  (i.e. Try using rosnode to list what orocos components you have instantiated or listing running ros nodes in the orocos deployer)

---

Originally posted by [drewm1980](https://answers.ros.org/users/1742/drewm1980/) with karma: 258 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2012-03-27**:
Interaction is quite seamless, tool-sets live next to each other. However not all code is written as an Orocos component or executed from the deployer. Most of us use both ROS and Orocos however.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-05**:
Hello. I would like to use also ROS for some real -time data analysis. I do not have experience in that and would like to use the data provided from ROS nodes for some real time analysis. Is there any help on this?